# error C2664: 'App *const' to 'QWidget *'

Tags: c++, qt, cinder

I'm trying to put an animated gif into my program.

However, when I follow the proper syntax

```
QMovie *hit1=new QMovie("BadExplosion.gif");
QLabel *processLabel=new QLabel(this);
processLabel->setMovie(hit1);
hit1->start();
```

in the

```
void TestApp::draw()
{
//this code and other drawing code here
}
```

I run into the error

error C2664: 'QLabel::QLabel(QWidget *, Qt::WindowFlags)' : Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TestApp *const' to 'QWidget *' on the line

```
QLabel *processLabel=new QLabel(this);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: TestApp is a custom class.

Comment: What is `TestApp`? A custom class? Or does it derive from something else?

Comment: Edited to say what TestApp is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TestApp` is a custom class, then it's perfectly normal that this code doesn't work.

Every UI element of Qt may take a parameter at construction, which is the `QWidget` that will act as a parent. This parent will notably have the responsibility for handling its children deletion. You should read more about this in the Qt Documentation (esp. the doc for [`QWidget constructor`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget)).

In your case, you shouldn't pass `this` to the QLabel constructor. You must pass another widget that'll become this `QLabel` parent.

The compiler shows clearly this problem with the message you got. It waits for a `QWidget`, but got your class instead (which doesn't inherit `QWidget` at any point).